# Inserting the succeeded word before 'and' conjunction using regex in python for various cases

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-group, python-re

The problem for different cases using examples of string.

**Case 1**

Input string:

> However, the gene of hBD-1 and LL-27 expression was not affected by acnes.

Code:

```py
import re
str_a = "However, the gene of hBD-1 and LL-27 expression was not affected by acnes."
out_a = re.sub(r'\b(\w+-\d+)\b(?! expression\b)', r'\1 expression', str_a)
print(out_a)
```

Output string:

> However, the gene of hBD-1 expression and LL-27 expression was not affected by acnes.

**Case 2**

Input string:

> The gene of acne and non-acne patients was affected by cancer.

Code:

```py
import re
str_b = "The gene of acne and non-acne patients was affected by cancer."
out_b = re.sub(r'\b(acne)\b(?! patients\b)', r'\1 patients', str_b)
print(out_b)
```

Output string:

> The gene of acne patients and non-acne patients was affected by cancer.

**Case 3**

Input string:

> Since, the gene of hBD-1 and LL-27 expression was not affected by acnes therefore the gene of acne and non-acne patients was affected by cancer.

Expected output string:

> Since, the gene of hBD-1 expression and LL-27 expression was not affected by acnes therefore the gene of acne patients and non-acne patients was affected by cancer.

**What I need:**

How to make these two regex for generic cases? I have to execute two different regex for two different strings. In case 3 how would I combine both the cases regex into a single regex. Kindly modify the regex or provide any other better solution.

Comment: I think running substitution twice is the best solution

Comment: MarkSouls thanks for your response. I have already executed substitution method twice its working but it seems manipulated I need some generic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might so is use 2 capture groups and use sub with a lambda checking for the groups.

```
import re

regex = r"\b(\w+-\d+)\b(?! expression\b)|\b(acne)\b(?! patients\b)"

s = ("However, the gene of hBD-1 and LL-27 expression was not affected by acnes.\n\n"
            "The gene of acne and non-acne patients was affected by cancer.\n\n"
            "Since, the gene of hBD-1 and LL-27 expression was not affected by acnes therefore the gene of acne and non-acne patients was affected by cancer.")

result = re.sub(regex, lambda x: x.group(1) + " expression" if x.group(1) else x.group(2) + " patients", s)
print(result)
```

Output

```
However, the gene of hBD-1 expression and LL-27 expression was not affected by acnes.

The gene of acne patients and non-acne patients was affected by cancer.

Since, the gene of hBD-1 expression and LL-27 expression was not affected by acnes therefore the gene of acne patients and non-acne patients was affected by cancer.
```

Comment: 4th bird, this was helpful. Thank u.